# Is there a directory, list, or other way to search for ocean crossing cruises from all cruise lines?

Tags: online-resources, sea-travel, cruising, north-america, oceania

As an alternative to flying, I'm considering to cruise from the east coast of Australia or somewhere in New Zealand to anywhere in North America.

The dates are flexible, but my preference is to depart in December 2016 or January 2017 and routes with island stops are superior.

Most cruise line sites are pretty bad for searching and they don't really have an easy way to search for just ocean crossing cruises and each line is a bit different.

Is there a directory, list, or other way to search all cruises departing around those dates across all cruise lines?

Comment: you may find some help in the answers to http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37853/how-can-i-find-out-when-cruise-ships-of-any-line-visit-a-particular-port?rq=1

Comment: So, presumably you've found *some* options (they [don't seem to be hard to find](https://www.google.com/search?q=transpacific+cruise)), but you're asking whether anybody has compiled a list of options across multiple cruise lines?

Comment: I have found some cruises but they are scattered across many sites. I'm looking for a definitive list of all routes or a search tool that is comprehensive.

Comment: Perhaps there is not enough interest in ocean crossings to warrant such a list.  I would hazard a guess that 90+% of folks looking to cruise want destinations to visit, not many days out in an "empty" ocean.

Comment: I'm interested in visiting destinations along the way, but I prefer one-way.

Answer (score 5):

[CruiseSheet](http://cruisesheet.com/) is going to be your best bet.  Given your departure and destination locations, here are the results for Cruise ships going from [Sydney to the West Coast of the United States](http://cruisesheet.com/?from=Sydney&to=California/West%20Coast).  The site catalogs cruises from all over the world into a searchable directory that allows you to optimize by departure and destination location, as well as price.  The service is free and was built by blogger and pickup artist [Tynan](http://tynan.com) (I am not Tynan nor am I affiliated with him or his site).  It was featured on the [Today Show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_n0zdzjc0c) as an excellent way of browsing cruises going all over the world to find the best possible deals.

Comment: Are you in any way affiliated with the site?

Comment: @drat  What would you like to know?  If you click the link, it shows those cruises going from Sydney (i.e. the east coast of Australia) to the West Coast of the U.S..

Comment: @JoErNanO  No, why?  Today Show says this is the best answer to this problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_n0zdzjc0c.  I don't understand why I'm being downvoted for answering the question?

Comment: @drat Ok, I changed it and added some detail.  How do you like it now?

Comment: @schulwitz mention the fact that you are not affiliated with the site in any way and you're good to go. ;)

Comment: @schulwitz thanks! The downvote was not mine, but I did upvote you now.